# iphone 7+ image not loading from image url

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageurl, iphone7plus

This is my code image are loading on all other devices but on iPhone 7+ its blank is their any bug or any correction I need to implement

```
[activityOnImage startAnimating];
 NSString *strUrl = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",useFullLinkObj.imageUrl]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[videoImage ecs_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl] placeholderImage:nil options:0 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
   [activityOnImage stopAnimating];
}];
```

Comment: What is `videoImage`? Is it a `UIImageView` or `UIImage`?

Comment: just sdweb_imageview its batter option

Comment: Try once with SDWebImage method with  `refreshcache` option. @Mukul

Comment: @Poles videoImage is UIImageView

Comment: @Mukul try my suggestion answer . your problem will be solve

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Bro i tried but it didn't make any difference

Comment: problem is only with iPhone 7+

Comment: @Mukul SDWebImage when you use is there any problem you face?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya no bro not before this

Comment: @Mukul in my xcode 8.2 and run in simulator 7+ its working fine SDWebImage library